# Angular modal with multiple subscribe methods

Tags: angular, rxjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm struggling to figure this one out, I've read that nested subscribes are bad.
I have a modal form that gets a list of items to select from, from a service, then once an item is selected the modal closes then I want to send the selection back to the service.  I've read a lot of Q&A on Stackoverflow, but I'm not sure how to do it?

```
public click_AddModalItem(includeAll: boolean) {
    // Modal InitialState Variables
    const initialState = {
        title: 'Select from List',
        dataList: {},
    };
    // Get Source Data list from backend
    this.service.getSourceData(includeAll)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            // Set Source data for Modal form
            initialState.dataList = data;
            this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(FrmSearchComponent, { initialState });
            this.modalRef.content.onClose
            .subscribe(modalResult => {
                // Get Modal result and add it to the backend
                console.log('Modal Result');
                console.log(modalResult);
                this.service.addSelectedItem(modalResult)
                .subscribe(
                    apiResponse => {
                    console.log(apiResponse);
                });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this currently not working at all for you, or are you just trying to avoid the nested subscriptions?

Comment: It is bad to have nested subscriptions. Read more on how to fix this http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/fixing-rxjs-anti-patterns and https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-best-practices-in-angular/#avoiding-nested-subscribes

Comment: It is working like a charm, but the researched I've done - everyone says to avoid nested subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

If they are three seperate tasks/observables which do not depends each other, then consider to use `forkJoin`

```
let observable1(param1);
let observable2(param2);
let observable3(param3);

let joinedObservables = forkJoin(observable1, observable2, observable3).subscribe(x => {
  let result1 = x[0];
  let result2 = x[1];
  let result3 = x[2];

  ...
});
```

If their results depends on each other you can use `switchMap`, `flatMap`, `mergeMap`, `exhaustMap` (check differences)

```
let resultObservable =  return this.observable1().pipe(mergeMap((param1) => {
  return this.observable2().pipe(map((param1) => {

    ....        

    return <result>;
  }));
}));

resultObservable.subscribe(x => {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten it with `mergeMap` or `switchMap`

to something like that:

```
public click_AddModalItem(includeAll: boolean) {
    // Get Source Data list from backend
    this.service
      .getSourceData(includeAll)
      .pipe(
        map(dataList => ({
          title: 'Select from List',
          dataList
        })),
        switchMap(initialState =>
          this.modalService.show(FrmSearchComponent, { initialState })
        ),
        tap(modalRef => (this.modalRef = modalRef)),
        switchMap(modalRef => modalRef.content.onClose),
        switchMap(modalResult => this.service.addSelectedItem(modalResult))
      )
      .subscribe(apiResponse => {
        console.log(apiResponse);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank Simonare, your code suggestion worked, with some minor changes.

```
const resultObservable = this.service.getSourceData(includeAll)
    .pipe(mergeMap(param1 => {
        initialState.dataList = param1;
        this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(FrmSearchComponent, {initialState});
        return this.modalRef.content.onClose
        .pipe(map(param2 => {
            return param2;
        }));
}));
resultObservable.subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```